# How can I use Caffe or TensorFlow in a Windows Universal App?

Tags: windows, neural-network, win-universal-app, tensorflow, caffe

I have trained several Caffe networks to do basic image classification tasks using Nvidia Digits. I am looking for a way to use the library functions and models in a Windows Universal App, or to convert my model to a TensorFlow model and use the mobile friendly options available there.
Evidently it is possible to use TensorFlow models in iOS and Android apps, but is there a way of using the Caffe or TensorFlow libraries (or models) in a Windows Universal App?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way of using the Caffe or TensorFlow libraries (or models) in a Windows Universal App?

There is no direct way in UWP app, they have not added support for Windows Runtime platform.

A possible way is to create a web service which can expose several methods, with these methods, using the libraries of Machine Intelligence to implement what you want.

In your UWP app, just use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) to consume web service.

Answer (score 0):

You may compile TensorFlow (difficult) or TensorFlow Lite (easy) as a static universal windows library, and link it with your uwp app.